# Displaying json Data into a list in angular using an array and httpClient

Tags: node.js, json, angular, mongodb, angular-httpclient

I am using Angular 8, to get JSON data and displaying it as a list, I do not know  where I am wrong, as it's not displaying any error. And the view is empty. If anyone have a good eye or understands the logic. I just started angular and don't seem to find what is wrong.

**video.service.ts**

```
private _getUrl= "/api/videos";
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

getVideos(){
 return this._http.get(this._getUrl).pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
}
```

**video.center.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-center',
  templateUrl: './video-center.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-center.component.css'],
  providers: [VideoService]
})
videos = [];
constructor(private _videoService: VideoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this._videoService.getVideos().subscribe(data => this.videos = data);     
    console.log("videos array", this.videos); // even this is not working !
  }
```

**video.list.component.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li (click)="onSelect(video)" *ngFor="let video of videos"><a>{{video.title}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you done the dependency injection of the service in *.component.ts file?

Comment: yes like so: `constructor(private _videoService: VideoService) { }`

Comment: Did you see network calls the in the browser's dev-tools? Whether the service is getting hit or not? If so then check the response part?

Comment: Why do you add the dot in front of the URL? I just liked to ask like @ngShravil.py whether you checked the network tab in the dev tools.

Comment: Sorry, the URL is on _getUrl:"api/videos" and yes its working fine in the network section and the response, it fetches the data, but for somehow it doesn't display it .an empty view! the HTML is fine too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular 4.3 the new HttpClient (@angular/common/http) was introduced in which the response object is json by default. So you don't need to map the answer.

So just return the http response:

```js
private _getUrl= "/api/videos";
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

getVideos(){
 return this._http.get(this._getUrl);
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I figured it out before I see this answer, by just trying. I thought that we needed to map through the data and pipe the answer, could you please elaborate more. so we don't need to map nor pipe the response?